# Ship to phone number disabled in Website Payments Pro settings

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm trying to collect customer's shipping phone number during Website Payments Pro Hosted checkout when people pay with credit card.

In PayPal Website Payments Pro Settings - Customer Information - Dispatch/delivery information there are tick boxes to make these fields required but they are disabled. I can make the billing phone number reqired but that's not included in the fields PayPal sending to my server.

Please help!

Comment: Have you tried contacting Paypal support?

Comment: I tried here:[link](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/Selling-on-your-website/Ship-to-phone-number-disabled-in-Website-Payments-Pro-settings/m-p/954354#U954354)
A moderator said to ask here.

Comment: And did you follow up on the response from the moderator?

Comment: The moderators response was to ask my question here, if you check the link...

Comment: Well.... I suppose that is one way for Paypal to offload responsibility.